# Filter strings using regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to use regular expressions to find a number of strings in a text file that meet all of the following requirements.

- Are of length 3
- Are made of all capital letters
- The first character is NOT 'A'
- The second character is NOT 'J'
- The third character is NOT 'K'

I started with this: `/[A-Z]{3}/` but this matches lowercase 3 letter strings as well for some reason.

Is this possible? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `[A-Z]` can only match lowercase letters if you enabled case insensitive matching.

Comment: You need to anchor your regexp, otherwise it will match anywhere in the line. So it should be `/^[A-Z]{3}$/`

Comment: You may use: `/[B-Z][A-IK-Z][A-JL-Z]/`

Comment: Besides, do you need to match  all Unicode letters or just ASCII ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to anchor the regexp so it matches the entire line. Otherwise, it will match a string that's longer than 3, but contains 3 uppercase letters together anywhere in it.

You can use character sets for each character.

```
/^[B-Z][A-IK-Z][A-JL-Z]$/
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line. `[B-Z]` matches any uppercase letter that isn't `A`, `[A-IK-Z]` matches any letter except `J`, and `[A-JL-Z]` matches any letter except `M`. `$` matches the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using lookahead:

```
^(?=[A-Z]{3}$)[^A][^J][^K]$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/JLEHJR/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the follow to return all the matches: `/\b(?=[A-Z])[^A](?=[A-Z])[^J](?!=[A-Z])[^K]\b/g`

It utilizes look-aheads and will return only 3 letter matches and can be relatively easily repeatable for any other variations A, J, K

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5s2Gkj/1